# jquery multiple forms processing on same page

Tags: jquery, html, forms, stripe-payments

I am trying to process multiple forms with jquery. I can process multiple buttons but I can't figure out to make it work with multiple forms. Following is the logic for different buttons and I need to edit it for forms.
HTML

```
<form id="myForm" action="/charge" method="post">
    <input type="button" id="buySocks" value="Buy Socks for $10">
    <input type="button" id="buyShirts" value="Buy Shirts for $30">
    <input type="button" id="buyPants" value="Buy Pants for $50">
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail" />
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh',
    token: function(token) {
            // append your token id and email, submit your form
          $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
        $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
        $("#myForm").submit();
    }
  });

  $('#buySocks').on('click', function(e) {
        $("#product").val("socks");
        openCheckout("Buy socks for $10", 1000);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#buyShirts').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#product").val("shirts");
    openCheckout("Buy shirts for $30", 3000);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('#buyPants').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#product").val("pants");
    openCheckout("Buy pants for $50", 5000);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  function openCheckout(description, amount)
  {
    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: description,
      amount: amount
    });
  }
  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
```

What I need to achieve is to be able to process:

```
<form id='form1' action='/url1' method='post'>
<input id='button1' type='submit' value='enroll'>
</form>

<form id='form2' action='/url2' method='post'>
<input id='button2' type='submit' value='enroll'>
</form>
```

Each form needs to get stripeToken as form needs to communicate to stripe.com. Each form has different plan type, price and description. Both forms are on same page.
Please advise.

EDIT:

Stripe custom button for single Form is below.

```
<form id="myForm" action="/charge" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeToken" name="stripeToken" />
    <input type="hidden" id="stripeEmail" name="stripeEmail" />
    <button id="customButton">Purchase</button>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: '{{ key }}',
    image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function (token) {
        // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
        $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
        $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
        $("#myForm").submit();
    }
});

$('#customButton').on('click', function (e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
        name: 'Stripe.com',
        description: '2 widgets',
        amount: 500
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

// Close Checkout on page navigation
$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    handler.close();
});
</script>
```

Comment: what about $('#formId').on('submit',function(e) {.... your code here ... });

Comment: Use classes for the inputs inside the form, so you can use the same class in each form. Then you can use `$("form").submit(function() ...)` and the function can use `$(this).find(".classname")` to find the appropriate inputs.

Comment: I tried that but it processes only one form as per standard jquery issue. If tow forms has any same ID as here I need to grab stripeToken for both forms it hides one of the form and processes alway second form. I don't know how to debug this sort of issue.

Comment: @Barmar I tried to assign classes with ID but I guess I am doing something wrong. Can you please post the code if it worked I will tick it and if it helped you still will get upvote for it.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the Stripe documentation for the API you're using. Got a link?

Comment: I'm familiar with stripe.js, not Stripe Checkout.

Comment: The standard button here https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/flask  for stripe is like "Pay with card" blue button but I have to align buttons with site style so I am using custom button method. For single form custom button I've added the code in question at the end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139628/discussion-between-shazia-nusrat-and-barmar).